# Getting error with CordovaLib (xCode 4.6)

Tags: cordova, xcode4.6

Here is the line that is giving me the error

```
if ([cdvViewController supportsOrientation:currentOrientation]) {
```

The error message is: Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' (aka 'enum UIDeviceOrientation') to different enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' (aka 'enum UIINterfaceOrientation')

Here is the complete block of code:

```
    // helper method to check the orientation and start updating headings
- (void)startHeadingWithFilter:(CLLocationDegrees)filter
{
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(headingOrientation)]) {
        UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if (currentOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) {
            CDVViewController* cdvViewController = (CDVViewController*)self.viewController;

            if ([cdvViewController supportsOrientation:currentOrientation]) {
                self.locationManager.headingOrientation = (CLDeviceOrientation)currentOrientation;
                // FYI UIDeviceOrientation and CLDeviceOrientation enums are currently the same
            }
        }
    }
    self.locationManager.headingFilter = filter;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    self.headingData.headingStatus = HEADINGSTARTING;
}
```